# How to efficiently perform random seeks in a file?

Tags: file, filereader, seek, leveldb

I have a file which is stored on disk and the records are written to the file with a custom record format. A bunch of records will represent a block. When you perform a read in the disk, you can only fetch a block instead of a record.

```
Block = physical record.
Data = logical record.
```

Every logical record has a unique offset in the file. It's closer to leveldb's record format.

Given a bunch of offsets, how would you efficiently read a logical record?

Comment: Is this some homework? What is your practical application? What operating system, file system, file size? Why the `leveldb` tag? Show some [MCVE] in your question

Answer (score 0):

In practice, on most current operating systems and hardware, **it does not matter** much.

Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) for more.

First, the operating system maintain a [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), which contains recently read or written pages. See also [linuxatemyram](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/). So many disk IO operations are not immediately done by the hardware, and they are not done in the order you requested them. Read more about [hard disk drive performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics).

Then, recall that more and more disks are [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)s (without any rotational delay, and a constant access time). And current [hard disk drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive)s don't use [CHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector) but [LBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) so the block address is not immediately related to its physical position (and the [disk controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_controller) itself handles the mapping).

In some cases, the kernel disk [driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) and [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) would reorganize pending disk requests.

However, you'll better **do disk IO on large enough buffers** (typically, several pages of 4Kbytes at least for each [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)).

On Linux, see also the [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html), [fsync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html), [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html), [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) system calls

> Given a bunch of offsets, how would you efficiently read a logical record?

You might order these offsets, but that practically won't change much and probably not at all. Be sure to benchmark.

In practice, use some library like [leveldb](https://github.com/google/leveldb) or [gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) (indexed files) or [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/). You could tune some parameters (buffer sizes), but you should trust the library for the rest.